# Send Image and table of string

Tags: angular

When creating a post, the user can also upload a image. All data are sent to the DB via a REST API built using the Django REST Framework.

I got this error inr Image 
the submitted data was not a file. check the encoding type on the form.

Service

```
addPosts(title: string, content: string, image: File, category: string, tags: string[]){
   let url = 'api/posts/post/';
   const formData = new FormData();

   formData.append("title", title);
   formData.append("content", content);
   formData.append("category", category);
   formData.append("tags", tags);
   formData.append("image", image);

   const post: Post = {title:title, content:content, image: image, category:category, tags:tags};

   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

   this.http.post(url, post, options)
   .subscribe(responseData => {
     this.posts.push(post);
     this.postsUpdate.next([...this.posts]);
   });
 }
```

when i use FormData i can't sent tags because i think FormData didn't support it and when i sent directly post i got 
the submitted data was not a file. check the encoding type on the form.

Comment: can you show error

Answer (score 0):

```
addPosts(title: string, content: string, image: File, category: string, tags: string[]){
   let url = 'api/posts/post/';
   const formData = new FormData();

   formData.append("title", title);
   formData.append("content", content);
   formData.append("category", category);
   formData.append("tags", tags);
   formData.append("image", image);

   const post: Post = {title:title, content:content, image: image, category:category, tags:tags};<------you set This

   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

**Set formData**

```
  this.http.post(url, post, options)<-----set Form Data instead of ` const post: Post`
   .subscribe(responseData => {
     this.posts.push(post);
     this.postsUpdate.next([...this.posts]);
   });
 }
```

Comment: formData.append("tags", tags);
in this line formData didn't accept table of string

Comment: tags means ? is

Comment: formData didn't accept tags: string[] it accept just type string

Comment: Tag is string isn’t it?

Comment: Is a table of string